# Correctly configuring a Q# test project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: programming, q#

I have some Q# code which I'm editing using visual studio code. The codebase is divided into a `src/` folder and a `test/` folder. The problem I'm having is that, although the tests do build and pass, VSCode claims that every use of something from the referenced `src/` folder is invalid.

For example, in this screen shot you can see red underlines as if there are errors, but actually the project builds and runs fine:

> [image: sample]

This is quite annoying, and I can't figure out what about my setup is causing it.

Here is `src/example.qs`:

```
namespace Example {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

    @EntryPoint()
    operation main() : Unit {
        Message("main");
    }

    operation op() : Int {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Here is `test/test.qs`:

```
namespace Example.Tests {
    
    open Example;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;

    @Test("ToffoliSimulator")
    operation test_op() : Unit {
        if (op() != 42) {
            fail "wrong result";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `src/src_project.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.13.20111004">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is `test/test_project.cs_proj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.13.20111004">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Xunit" Version="0.13.20111004" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\src\src_project.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run tests",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test/test_project.csproj",
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

And finally here is `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "debug",
            "program": "dotnet",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/src_project.csproj",
                "-s",
                "ToffoliSimulator",
            ],
            "request":"launch",
            "logging": {
                "moduleLoad": false
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem when imported the compiled code into a python host file

Answer (score 1):

A current limitation of the extensions (both VS and VS Code) is that they are only able to deal with exactly one workspace folder, and anything outside that folder doesn't exist as far as the extension is concerned. I suspect you are opening the folder with the test project in VS Code, correct? If so, then the extension is unaware of the src folder, since that folder is not contained in the workspace folder (the test folder). If you instead open a folder that contains both the src and the test folder, then everything should work fine.

Comment: The directory structure is currently that the `.vscode`, `src`, and `test` folders are all inside the folder I am opening in VSCode. I tried putting `src` and `test` both under a temporary folder next to `.vscode`, but the error persisted.

Comment: @CraigGidney Could you check whether there are any errors in the output window for the Q# Language Extension?

Comment: I re-opened the project and hit start debugging and ran the tests. There was no output of any kind in the "output" tab. I did get an unrelated warning in "terminal output" about using deprecated syntax, which I fixed.